# How to find the index of a string on array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, linux

I'm trying to find out the index on the local storage of my website.
My local storage looks like this

["Hello, this, is, not", "banana, apple, fruit, kiwi", "phone, pepper, salt, potatoe"]

I would like to find the index of the string **banana, apple, fruit, kiwi**.
And then **proceed to erase it, delete from the local storage**

This is my code.

```
function deleteElement() {
        var elementToDelete =document.getElementById('deleteElement').value;
        console.log(elementToDelete);
        const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
        console.log(myArray);

        var storage = window.localStorage;
        if (myArray.indexOf(finder)) {

            console.log("True")
            myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(elementToDelete),1);
            console.log(myArray.splice(2,1));
            storage.setItem("things", JSON.stringify(myArray));




        } else {
            console.log("Not found")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the index for -1.

If not -1 then only splice the array.Otherwise it will remove another element

```
let index = myArray.indexOf(elementToDelete)
if (index != -1)
  myArray.splice(index, 1);
storage.setItem("things", JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

```js
let myArray = ["Hello, this, is, not", "banana, apple, fruit, kiwi", "phone, pepper, salt, potatoe"]
let elementToDelete = "banana, apple, fruit, kiwiss" //hardcoded for example
let index = myArray.indexOf(elementToDelete)
if (index != -1)
  myArray.splice(index, 1);  
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding index and splice, One way is use `filter` out you want delete and update the `localStorage`

```js
const arr = [
  "Hello, this, is, not",
  "banana, apple, fruit, kiwi",
  "phone, pepper, salt, potatoe",
];

const updated = arr.filter((item) => !item.includes("banana"));
// window.localStorage("things", JSON.stringify(updated));

console.log(updated);

// Alternatively
const index = arr.findIndex((item) => item.includes("banana"));

if (index > -1) {
  // delete and update local storage
  console.log("found element and index ", index);
}
```

Comment: Hey how do you add this kind of snippet which allows you to run and copy?

Comment: @SuparnoSaha, When you are adding the answer, Click on "<>" icon which will open the code sandbox, you can run, verify and save to answer.

Comment: Cool I didn't knew about that